# webkitAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend not working

Tags: javascript, css

hey guys i am trying to get my `webkitAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend` to fire in my custom animation but somehow nothing is happening , i am following the examples at MDN , but still without much success , i basically have the following code .

HTML code :

```
<div id="tst">

</div>
```

JS code :

```
function showMessage() {
                alert('Transition has finished');
            }

            var element = document.getElementById("tst");
            element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", showMessage, false);
```

CSS code :

```
#tst {
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                background: red;
                position: relative;
                -webkit-animation-name: anim;
                -o-animation-name: anim;
                animation-name: anim;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
                -o-animation-duration: 6s;
                animation-duration: 6s;
            }

            @keyframes anim {
                0% {
                    left: 50%
                }
                100% {
                    left: 0;
                }
            }
```

on completion of the custom animation the event is not firing. Why ??

I am following the [MDN doc's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) here and running my tests in Mozilla Firefox.

Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpu3jsfa/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `addEventListener` call is wrong, the first parameter of `addEventListener` is:

[Quoted from the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener)

> - *type* **of type** DOMString
>
> The event type for which the user is registering

You cannot specify 3 types of event in vanilla Javascript, it is not a CSS selector (nor a jQuery selector), you need to specify them separately:

```
function showMessage() {
    alert('Transition has finished');
}

var element = document.getElementById("tst");
element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", showMessage, false);
element.addEventListener("oAnimationEnd"     , showMessage, false);
element.addEventListener("msAnimationEnd"    , showMessage, false);
element.addEventListener("animationend"      , showMessage, false);
```

[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/t6yf7kxb/)

**EDIT**:

Jquery .on event doesn't do nothing of magic, how can you read from [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L798), it's just a recursive call:

```
 for ( type in types ) {this.on( type, selector, data, types[ type ], one );}
```

Comment: just another supplementary question , what is the "ability to add multiple events in a single listener function eg. on(),  known in Jquery ?? "