# Stopping sequential functions/animations with clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript, css

This code sample works, it does not work with animations of the same duration instead of just an alert.

```
<script>
    var timeoutOne = null,
        timeoutTwo = null,
        timeoutThree = null;

    function alertOne() {

        alert('first message');
        timeoutOne = setTimeout(alertTwo, 3000);

    }

    function alertTwo() {

        alert('second message');
        timeoutTwo = setTimeout(alertThree, 1000);

    }

    function alertThree() {

        alert('third message');
        timeoutThree = setTimeout(alertFour, 1000);

    }

    function alertFour() {

        alert('fourth message');

    }

    function startCountdown() {

        alertOne();

    }

    function stopCountdown() {

        clearTimeout(timeoutOne);
        clearTimeout(timeoutTwo);
        clearTimeout(timeoutThree);

    }
</script>
```

*I intended to have multiple links but I'm limited to two. The first link is the working demo of the project. The second is all of the code discussed in the question*

[working-demo](http://360mediahub.com/current/)

[different-code](http://360mediahub.com/code/)

I'm working on this project that involves animation and re-calculation of elements/repositioning in the event of a rescale and I can't seem to get it to work. I've been working on this for over a month now, and I've tried at least 20 different iterations.

*Note: the links are highlighted code (except for the actual demo of the interactive display).*

The timeout-testing link is a short demonstration of four, sequential-alerts being stopped by a single button. This is the effect I'm trying to accomplish with regard to the animation. *note that this is just code, not an actual alert/button interface*

The shortened-script is the specific problematic-code taken out of the problematic script.

My solution so far is to use three scripts, the calculated/positioned/animated elements are removed, re-added, the three main functions of setup,position,dimensions are recalled as if it was a new page... but I have three scripts so it breaks after the fourth re-scale while the animation is running. I've tried to switch back and forward between two scripts but it doesn't work going from script 2 to 1.

The alert example and shortened-script is my new attempt which tries not to use the three scripts method done in the working demo.

I haven't tried promises/deferred yet. I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

The three scripts used in the working demo are first,second,third-script respectively.

They are pretty much copies of each other with minor differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `animationend` event is more reliable for what I think you're trying to do. What's nice is that you don't have to try and time the exact moment an animation finishes; you instead rely on the browser. Have a look at this example.

```js
var step_one = document.querySelector('.step.one');
var step_two = document.querySelector('.step.two');

function stepOneHandler() {
  step_two.classList.add('go');
}

step_one.classList.add('go');

step_one.addEventListener('animationend', stepOneHandler);
```

```css
@keyframes move-one-right {
  to { transform: translateX(3em); }
}

@keyframes move-two-right {
  to { transform: translateX(6em); }
}

.step {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.step.one.go {
  animation: 1s move-one-right forwards;
}

.step.two.go {
  animation: 1s move-two-right forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="step one"></div>
<div class="step two"></div>
```

Comment: Do you think that I need @keyframes? I think my animations are pretty smooth, unless the @keyframes replaces my setTimeouts which cause the sequential animation? Those aren't bad either, thanks for your answer, I'm going to try and implement it and see, I was looking for alternative solutions like using stoppable gifs or embedding a youtube video player instead.

Comment: I realize your solution uses a different way to initialize the animation. I'm trying to implement the idea of detecting when animation has ended. I'm looking at a stack overflow question which has the same idea as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894772/webkitanimationend-msanimationend-animationend-not-working

Comment: looks like this is what I was looking for, thanks for your answer/help.